# Deplyoing stand-alone apache + subversion?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apache-http-server, svn

Would it be possible to make a apache + subversion install and somehow making it independent so it has all the libs it needs with him? Normally apache doesn't depend on much to build it and run it on a fresh-installed machine.

However, subversion has lots of dependencies, which can be a pain in the ass to track down.

Does there exist some kind of precompiled version of subversion and apache together?
Or how could I make something that I can quickly redeploy on another pc without putting any files on it? IE it should be runnable from a stick.However, building it is also an option if we just install `build-essential`.

(some things I thought of myself is trying to compile it, and use tons of options to include all library dependencies without doing apt-get install, maybe it's possible to do an apt-get install in a specific library and copy those files? Or maybe you could extract the .deb package)

using apt-get install on the machine is **not** an option, we want files to be **gone** when they delete them from their disk. Do not question me about why we want this, it's just a requirement for us.

**it just needs to work on debian based OS's like ubuntu & debian self.**

Answer (score 1):

Try [subversion edge](http://www.collab.net/products/subversion), which is an open source version controlling software with apche+viewvc+subversion with a pretty good GUI

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it work for you, but a lot of times people need something like this a disk image would work.  Use one that has a free VM player, like VirtualBox or others.  Make a minimal OS install.  Then you have one disk image to move about, and delete.

If you do the build your own route, i'd say install in /opt/something.  Keep installing everything there, and when you want to delete it, you have one directory to remove.